# React with ASP.NET Core not displaying data

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm learnig to integrate React with ASP.NET Core applications, i created a new React with ASP.NET Core project in .NET 6.0 with SQL Server database, this is the code i used to display the content of STudent table:

StudentController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;

    public StudentController(ApplicationDbContext dbcontext)
    {
        _dbcontext = dbcontext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetStudents")]
    public IActionResult GetStudents()
    {
        List<Student> students =_dbcontext.Student.ToList();
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, students);
    }
}
```

Student.js:

```
import {React, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
    //create useState
    const [students, setStudents] = useState([])
    //call api
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("api/Student/GetStudents")
            .then(response => { return response.json() })
            .then(responseJson => {
                setStudents(responseJson)
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Students</h1>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <table className="table table-stripped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Course Enrolled</th>
                            </tr>
                            
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                students.map((item) => (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{item.Id}</td>
                                        <td>{item.Name}</td>
                                        <td>{item.Course}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ))
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}     
export default App;
```

AppRoutes.js:

```
import { default as Student } from "./components/Student";

const AppRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/students',
    element: <Student />
  }

];

export default AppRoutes;
```

The problem is that this code didn't display any data from the database, it displays only the header of the table with no rows. What's wrong with the code? am i missing anything?

Comment: Did u check if the request was success or tried to console.log the response

Comment: When you use swagger, do you get any data out of the API? On the network tab, is there data when React makes the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your browser's developer tools to check for any error messages.

[image]
If you have the error on the picture, it's probably because you didn't change the `setupProxy.js` file(check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022#verify-ports)). Please add your Api path to the `context` in this file:

```
const context =  [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/api/Student/GetStudents"
];
```

Complete setupProxy.js file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:59947';

const context =  [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/api/Student/GetStudents"
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

Also, change the `tbody` section in `Student.js` to this:

```
<tbody>
    {
        students.map(item => 
           <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.id}</td>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.course}</td>
           </tr>
        )
    }
</tbody>
```

You need to add `key` prop to it, if you didn't do something special, the property name should be lower case.

Test Result:
[image]